# How do I remove the cruft at the start of my posh-git window title?

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I'm using posh-git for my powershell window, and the prompt is perfect:

```
S:\Repos\DevTools [master ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]>
```

But the title of the window has extra cruft at the start:

```
posh~git ~ DevTools [master]
```

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the extra `posh~git ~`?  It doesn't seem necessary or useful, though maybe I simply don't understand what it is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, would you look at that!  It got fixed just today!
https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/pull/567

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the accepted answer, there is a customisation option available which will let you set a custom prefix, or alternatively no prefix.

In your Powershell profile (find it by running `$Profile`, in my case it is this file here: `C:\Users\myuser\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`) add the following:

```
Import-Module posh-git # should already exist if you have posh-git set up
$GitPromptSettings.EnableWindowTitle = $TRUE # or set it to a string if you want a different custom prefix
$GitPromptSettings.AdminTitlePrefixText = "" # optional, remove the prefix when running as admin
```

Restart your session and you should be up and running.

Answer (score 1):

As of posh-git 1.0.0, the `posh~git ~` prefix is no longer present by default.

Note also that the `EnableWindowTitle` property no longer exists in the global `$GitPromptSettings` object; this property is now called `WindowTitle` and is a function that you can override to customise the prompt, e.g. in your [`$profile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles).

For example, the below changes the window title text to use [Unicode character 1f6e1 (the shield symbol)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F6E1) instead of the default text `Admin:`  when running elevated:

```
$global:GitPromptSettings.WindowTitle = {
    param($GitStatus, [bool]$IsAdmin)
        "$(if ($IsAdmin) {"`u{1f6e1} "})$(if ($GitStatus) {"$($GitStatus.RepoName) [$($GitStatus.Branch)]"} else {Get-PromptPath}) - PowerShell $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major).$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor) $(if ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {'32-bit '})($PID)"
}
```